# How many sql queries does this scenario make (PHP)?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Ok, so if I set into a variable an sql_query like so:

```
$query = mysql_query("..");
```

and call multiple mysql_result's like so:

```
mysql_result($query, 0);
mysql_result($query, 1);
mysql_result($query, 2);
```

How many queries will the page call to the server?
Only once? or three times?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you execute `mysql_query`, **It executes the sql** and it keeps the result in an internal result structure. Next time when you call `mysql_result`, it fetches from that internal result.

For buffered query the reusult will be copying from MySQL server to PHP as soon as mysql_query is executed. For un-buffered query it'll be copied lazily.

So in both case **Query executes only one time**. But for un-buffered query it'll be fetched from MySQL server. every time you call `mysql_result` or `mysq_fetch_*`.<sup>[Buffered and Unbuffered queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.concepts.buffering.php)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You have given the answer yourself. If you are calling "query" function once, then it will only 
execute once no matter how many times you parse its return value

```
$query = mysql_query("..");
```

When you run the above code then query gets executed and the returned resource is in $query variable. Then you can fetch data from it multiple times but query wont run again.

Answer (score 0):

Here will be one query with database that's means Server. mysql_result() should not be mixed with calls to other functions that deal with the result set.

For more information you can visit : http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-result.php

Answer (score 0):

Only *mysql_query* is executing against the mysql server. **Only one query**

mysql_result only fetches data from a mysql resource, it doesn't matter if you have previously gotten it from a query in code or managed to get it from another source.

From PHP 5.5.0 onwards this function is deprecated; the new way to perform this action would be to create a **mysqli** object and use over the functions **mysqli::query** and **mysqli::fetch_field**